# Can't add {message} variable to order_conf mail template

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

On my `classes/PaymentModule.php` I have declared `'{message}' => $customer_message` (between other vars) but still my customers see `Wiadomość: {message}`
 in mails which they recieved.

What do I wrong? Maybe declare {message} var in PaymentModule.php is not enough?

UDPATE:

this is standard PaymentModule.php code in Prestashop 1.6.2.1 with added {message} variable:

```
$customer_message = $order->getFirstMessage();
$data = array(
            '{firstname}' => $this->context->customer->firstname,
            '{lastname}' => $this->context->customer->lastname,
            '{email}' => $this->context->customer->email,
            '{delivery_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, "\n"),
            '{invoice_block_txt}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, "\n"),
            '{delivery_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($delivery, '<br />', array(
                'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
                'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
            )),
            '{invoice_block_html}' => $this->_getFormatedAddress($invoice, '<br />', array(
                    'firstname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>',
                    'lastname'    => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">%s</span>'
            )),
            '{delivery_company}' => $delivery->company,
            '{delivery_firstname}' => $delivery->firstname,
            '{delivery_lastname}' => $delivery->lastname,
            '{delivery_address1}' => $delivery->address1,
            '{delivery_address2}' => $delivery->address2,
            '{delivery_city}' => $delivery->city,
            '{delivery_postal_code}' => $delivery->postcode,
            '{delivery_country}' => $delivery->country,
            '{delivery_state}' => $delivery->id_state ? $delivery_state->name : '',
            '{delivery_phone}' => ($delivery->phone) ? $delivery->phone : $delivery->phone_mobile,
            '{delivery_other}' => $delivery->other,
            '{invoice_company}' => $invoice->company,
            '{invoice_vat_number}' => $invoice->vat_number,
            '{invoice_firstname}' => $invoice->firstname,
            '{invoice_lastname}' => $invoice->lastname,
            '{invoice_address2}' => $invoice->address2,
            '{invoice_address1}' => $invoice->address1,
            '{invoice_city}' => $invoice->city,
            '{invoice_postal_code}' => $invoice->postcode,
            '{invoice_country}' => $invoice->country,
            '{invoice_state}' => $invoice->id_state ? $invoice_state->name : '',
            '{invoice_phone}' => ($invoice->phone) ? $invoice->phone : $invoice->phone_mobile,
            '{invoice_other}' => $invoice->other,
            '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
            '{date}' => Tools::displayDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), null, 1),
            '{carrier}' => ($virtual_product || !isset($carrier->name)) ? Tools::displayError('No carrier') : $carrier->name,
            '{payment}' => Tools::substr($order->payment, 0, 32),
            '{products}' => $product_list_html,
            '{products_txt}' => $product_list_txt,
            '{discounts}' => $cart_rules_list_html,
            '{discounts_txt}' => $cart_rules_list_txt,
            '{total_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_paid, $this->context->currency, false),
            '{total_products}' => Tools::displayPrice(Product::getTaxCalculationMethod() == PS_TAX_EXC ? $order->total_products : $order->total_products_wt, $this->context->currency, false),
            '{total_discounts}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_discounts, $this->context->currency, false),
            '{total_shipping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_shipping, $this->context->currency, false),
            '{total_wrapping}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_wrapping, $this->context->currency, false),
            '{message}' => $customer_message,
            '{total_tax_paid}' => Tools::displayPrice(($order->total_products_wt - $order->total_products) + ($order->total_shipping_tax_incl - $order->total_shipping_tax_excl), $this->context->currency, false));
```

In order_conf.html:

```
...
Wiadomość: {message}
....
```

Comment: Can you show some code? The code where you declare your smarty variable and the template that use this variable.

Comment: I can't see in your `$data` array the `{message}` declaration.

Comment: Oh sorry, I copied clean code with other shop... Added

Answer (score 0):

ou should use below function if not already using it. 
Example:

```
$id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
$heading = Mail::l('Message Received', (int)$id_lang);
Mail::Send(
                (int)$id_lang,
                'order_conf',
                $heading,
                $data,
                $this->context->customer->email,
                null,
                null,
                $this->context->shop->name,
                null,
                null,
                _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodule/mail/',
                false,
                1
                );
```

mail template should be located in `'mymodule/mail/en/order_conf.html'` make languages directories according to your languages like /en , /fr, /nl

Answer (score 0):

With Prestashop 1.7, I’ve tested with

```
'{message}'  => 'hello',
```

And it displays in email : hello

Are you sure you have something in `$customer_message` ?

It can be more complicated with some variables. Have a look at `$product_list_html`

You will see it is an array and there is :

```
$product_list_html = $this->getEmailTemplateContent('order_conf_product_list.tpl', Mail::TYPE_HTML, $product_var_tpl_list);
```

It uses an other template to build the list of product `(order_conf_product_list.tpl)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that post is 3 years old but the solution is not using

```php
$customer_message
```

but

```php
$customer_message->message
```